# TSQL: Global Script Variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am making use of variables in my TSQL queries. As my script has grown, I have separated each part by `GO`, now the problem is I need access to variables at the top of my script.

How can I still access these variables?

Hopefully, this is something simple and straightforward.

Thanks all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GO is used to separate batch of t-sql, Variables have local scope and are only visible within the batch or procedure where they are defined.

Your best best is probably to store the global stuff in a temp table, or if they are constant create a stored proc. to pull them at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late, but if you're using SSMS, you can put it in [SQLCMD Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) and define variables that way. You can't change the variables once you've defined them, but it's still handy to know.

```
:setvar MyVariable "FooBar"

Select Foo from Bar where FooBar = '$(FooBar)'
GO
Insert Into Bar(FooBar) Values ('$(FooBar)')
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem.

My solution:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#range') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #range
GO

SELECT  '06/01/15' STARTING_DATE, '06/30/15' ENDING_DATE
INTO    #range
GO

SELECT  f.*
FROM    foo f
INNER JOIN #range r ON f.date_field BETWEEN r.starting_date AND r.ending_date
GO

SELECT  b.*
FROM    bar b
INNER JOIN #range r ON b.date_field BETWEEN r.starting_date AND r.ending_date
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#range') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #range
GO
```